# About the Poincaré metric isometry and automorphism on the unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, metric-spaces, isometry

Consider two domains $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ in $\mathbb{C}$ with the corresponding metrics $g|d z|^2$ and $h|d w|^2$ respectively. Let $d_1$ be the distance function induced from $g|d z|^2$, and $d_2$ that from $h|d w|^2$.
We say a map $f$ smooth if it is $C^{\infty}$ as a map from $\Omega_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ to $\Omega_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. Given a smooth bijection $f: \Omega_1 \rightarrow \Omega_2$, we call $f$ is an isometry if $f$ is distance-preserving in the sense that $d_1(z, w)=d_2(f(z), f(w))$ for any two points $z, w \in \Omega_1$.

Consider the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$ with its standard Poincaré metric.
$$
d s_P^2=\frac{4}{\left(1-|z|^2\right)^2}|d z|^2 .
$$

In the lecture we checked that any automorphism (holomorphic bijection) of $\mathbb{D}$ must be a holomorphic isometry. As a corollary we solved the corresponding distance function $d$ (called the Poincaré distance) induced from the Poincaré metric.

Question:

Given any isometry $f$ of $\mathbb{D}$ with respect to the Poincare distance, then either $f$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{D}$ or its conjugate $\bar{f}$ is so}(why?). If we drop the assumption that an isometry is smooth, can we get the same conclusion?

I can only figure out $|f(z)|$ which is equal to $|\frac{z-\beta}{1-\bar{\beta}z}|$(where $\beta=f^{-1}(0)$).S ince $d(0,z)=\ln^{\frac{1-|z|}{1+|z|}}$ ，f is an isometry , thus $d(\beta,z)=d(0,f(z))$, and any automorphism of D is a holomorphic isometry. We have $d(\beta,z)=d(0,\frac{z-\beta}{1-\bar{\beta}z})=d(0,f(z))$, so this is all I can get. But how to proof either $f$ or $\bar{f}$ is actually equal to $\frac{z-\beta}{1-\bar{\beta}z}e^{i\theta}$?

This is my first time to ask questions in this community. Is there anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By comments from @ziqishen, its enough to consider $f(0) = 0$. So lets assume $f(0) = 0$.
Since we have,
$d(0,z) = d(f(0), f(z))$, we get, $|z| = \frac{|f(z)-f(0)|}{|1-f(0)^* f(z)|} \implies z = \frac{(f(z)-f(0))e^{j A(z)}}{1-f(0)^* f(z)} $.

Hence if $f(0) = 0$, we have that, $|f(z)| = |z|$. Hence $f(z) = ze^{j A(z)}$.

Let $A(z) \in [-\pi,\pi)$.

Prove that $\frac{|r_1 - r_2 e^{j \theta}|}{|1-r_1 r_2 e^{j \theta}|} = constant < 1$ has a unique solution $\gamma$ with $\theta = + \gamma$ or $\theta = - \gamma$ for fixed $r_1,r_2 \neq 0$.

$ d(f(r_1),f(r_2)) = d(r_1,r_2) = d(r_1 e^{j \theta},r_2 e^{j \theta}) =  d(f(r_1 e^{j \theta}),f(r_2 e^{j \theta}))$

Note that $f(z) = z e^{j A(z)}$. Using this in above equation we get:
$d(r_1,r_2) = d(f(r_1),f(r_2)) = d(f(r_1 e^{j \theta}),f(r_2 e^{j \theta})) \implies \frac{|r_1 - r_2|}{|1-r_1 r_2|} = \frac{|r_1 - r_2 e^{j (A(r_1)-A(r_2)}|}{|1-r_1 r_2 e^{j (A(r_1)-A(r_2)}|} = \frac{|r_1 - r_2 e^{j (A(r_1 e^{j \theta})-A(r_2 e^{j \theta})}|}{|1+r_1 r_2 e^{j (A(r_1 e^{j \theta})-A(r_2 e^{j \theta})}|} $.

Hence $e^{j (A(r_1 e^{j \theta})-A(r_2 e^{j \theta}) )}= e^{j(A(r_1)-A(r_2) )}= 1$ for fixed $r_1$ and $r_2$.

Hence for a fixed $r^*$ and for every other $r, \theta$, $e^{j(A(r e^{j \theta}))}= e^{j A(r^* e^{j \theta})}$.

Now by similar argument i.e., with $r_1 = r_2 = r$, $e^{j(A(r e^{j (h+\theta)}) - A(r e^{j \theta}))} = e^{j \pm (A(r e^{j h}) - A(r))} = e^{j \pm h}$

Using above, now assuming continuity of derivative of $g(t) = A(re^{jt})$, except at points where $A(re^{j \theta}) = -\pi$ (these points are assumed to be finitely many), the derivative of $A(re^{j\theta})$ w.r.t $\theta$ exists with derivative $\pm 1$, and we have  $A(re^{j \theta})$ is linear in $\theta$ for a fixed $r$ i.e., of the form $s(r) \theta + g(r)$ with $s(r) = \pm 1$.

But by $A(r e^{j \theta}) = A(r^* e^{j \theta})$, we have that $s(r) = s(r^*) =\pm 1$ and $g(r) = g(r^*)$.

we have that $f(r e^{j \theta}) = r e^{j(s \theta + g)}$ for some constants $s=\pm 1, g$.

Comment: Sorry.I still have quetions.If $f(0)=0$,then why $f(z)$ or $\bar{f}$ is holomorphic?Since we don't know  whether $B(z)$ is holomorphic. The condition in this question about $f$ is only smooth in $D^2$.

Comment: And how to use the condition "smooth"?.The next quetion is asking whether "smooth" can be removed. I'll try to follow your answer.Give me some time.

Comment: Prove that $\frac{|r_1-r_2 e^{j \theta}|}{|1-r_1 r_2 e^{j \theta}|} = constant$ for a fixed $r_1,r_2$ is solved by a unique $\gamma$ with $\theta = \gamma$ or $\theta = -\gamma$. This proves that $A(z e^{j \theta}) -A(z_0 e^{j \theta_0})= A(z)-A(z_0) $ or $ = - (A(z)-A(z_0))$  $\forall z,z_0 \text{ with } |z| = r_1$ and $|z_0| = r_2$. I did not try further. Regarding smoothness, you need to use it in proving the statement i asked you to try to justify. So far its not needed.

Comment: As mentioned in above comment, we have for $f(0) = 0$, for a fixed $r^*$ and for every other $r, \theta$, $A(r e^{j \theta}) = A(r^* e^{j \theta})$. Now by similar argument i..e., with $r_1 = r_2$, $A(z e^{j 2\theta}) - A(z e^{j \theta}) $ $ = A(z e^{j \theta}) - A(z)$ or $=A(z e^{j \theta}) - A(z)$. Using this try justifying by smoothness of $A(z )$ that we have  $A(re^{j \theta})$ is linear in $\theta$ for a fixed $r$ or $A(z) = constant$.

Comment: @ziqishen Updated my answer for $f(0) = 0$ case.

Comment: If we take $g(z)=\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{1-\overline{f(0)}f(z)}$, then $g(0)=0$, and it's a smooth isometry, and we proof $g$ or $\bar{g}$  is  holomorphic , then we're done.The quetion is your proof of case"0".Note that $A\left(r_1 e^{j \theta}\right)-A\left(r_2 e^{j \theta}\right)=A\left(r_1\right)-A\left(r_2\right)$.You fixed $r_{2}$ ,but the right side is also up to $r_1$,that's not const when $r_{1}$ changes.

Comment: @ziqishen edited my answer and removed unnecessary things. Take a look and let me know.

Comment: I didn't check the last part, where you prove $A(z)$ is linear about $\theta$.And I saw your results, actually we need know what value 's' is to figure out whether $f$ or bar is holomorphic. Now give my proof by following your idea. Let we set $A(z) \in [-\pi,\pi]$, $d(f\left(r\right), f(re^{i\theta}))=d\left(r, re^{\theta}\right)$,thus we have $A\left(re^{j \theta}\right)-A\left(r\right)=+\- \theta$.Note that $f$ is smooth, by the continuity of $f$.We can have $A (z)-A(r)=0 or -2\theta $.Since $A(z)$ stay unchanged if $\theta$ is fixed. $A(z)=A(r_{0})=Const$ or $A(z)=-2\theta+A(r_{0})$.Done.

Comment: There are problems if we don't limit $A(z)$. because $+\- 2k\pi$ dosen't change $f(z)$,A(z) need not be smooth or even continuity. Last ，$A(z)=const $ or $A(z)=-2\theta +const$ because for continuity, for any $\theta \neq 0 \ \pi $,any sequences $\theta_{k}$ converge to $\theta$, $A(z)$ can't have two form ,otherwise contradict to continuity of $f$,so we find in a small neighbour of $\theta$,$A(z)$ has  one form ,and you can extend that neighbour by continuity.If there exists $\theta_{0}$ $A(z_{0}) $has the other form ,there may be a sup neighbour between $\theta ,\theta_{0}$

Comment: By continuity,you can still extend , contradicting to sup.So $A(z)$ can only have one form.It's either const or $-2\theta+const$.$f(z)=z*const$ or $\bar{f} = z*const $.Done

Comment: But I'm not definitely sure that my proof is right?So if my proof has mistakes , please let me know.

Comment: I think you are correct.  Its either $f(z) = r e^{j (\theta + constant)}$ or $f(z) = r e^{j (-\theta + constant)}$.

Comment: Sir,I have accepted for your answer.Thanks for your persistence and your help. I'm more relaxed than before ,this is impossible without your help,though I still have questions about the problem .And have a nice day!

Comment: Cheers mate ! All the best !